# How to blink an object in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, winforms, object, controls

I have many controls in my form, like pictureboxes, buttons and textboxes. I made a timer that will blink a control when I ask.

How do I pass the control as a reference, so I could choose easily, which control to blink?

I tried to make a class, "BlinkingObject.vb", to where I pass the control and colors as properties, but I can't make this a reference of the original object...
The idea was, that my timer picks the control from BlinkingObject.vb -class and then changes its backcolor...

I want to have custom colors (upcolor and downcolor) and the control's original background will be needed also.

Comment: Is this a WinForm or WebForm application?

Comment: I suppose this is WinForm because I don't do web apps..

Comment: I would say `WPF` would be a good choice since it uses `Animation` for many parts of their controls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code blinks the control, and doesn't hog the UI thread

```
' you need the delegate because there is no Action(of byref)
Private Delegate Sub blinkDel(ByRef myControl As Control, ByVal c As Color)

' the Sub you call to blink the control
Public Shared Sub Blink(ByRef myControl As Control, ByVal c As Color)
    ' call performBlink asynchronously as not to take up time on the UI thread
    CType(AddressOf performBlink, blinkDel).BeginInvoke(myControl, c, Nothing, Nothing)
End Sub

' performs the blinking actions
Private Shared Sub performBlink(ByRef myControl As Control, ByVal blinkColor As Color)
    ' invoke the action of setting the backcolor on the UI thread
    myControl.Invoke(New blinkDel(AddressOf setBackColor), myControl, blinkColor)
    ' sleep this thread for how long it should blink
    Thread.Sleep(100)
    ' restore the back color on the UI thread
    myControl.Invoke(New blinkDel(AddressOf setBackColor), myControl, Color.White)
End Sub

' need a named sub because you can't have a ByRef in a lambda (otherwise would be inside performBlink)
Private Shared Sub setBackColor(ByRef myControl As Control, ByVal c As Color)
    myControl.BackColor = c
End Sub

' calling it inside a timer
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Blink(TextBox1, Color.Black)
End Sub
```

Comment: Looking at this again, your original request to pass the control by ref should have been ignored since objects references are passed to methods. In my answer, you could remove all `ByRef`, and then use an `Action(Of Control, Color)` instead of a custom delegate. I'll leave my answer as it is however, since it was accepted that way.